# Why is my fetch api in javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Home.html**

```
<button id="submit-form-btn" onclick="getFormData()" name="submit-btn">Submit</button>
<script>
    function getFormData() {
        let user =
        {
            "username": "X_X",
            "password": "123"
        }

        fetch("index.php",
            {
                "method": "POST",
                "mode": "cors",
                "headers":
                {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;"
                },
                "body": JSON.stringify(user)
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.text();
            }).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
    }
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST))
{
    $data = file_get_contents(("php://input"));
    $user = json_decode($data);
    echo $user["username"];
}
?>
```

I've tried the same code but with an empty html file and it worked with the same php file (index.php) and it worked. When using it in the home.html file, I'm getting this error in the inspector

> "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

[image]

I tried chatgpt and youtube tutorials and it seems that everything is fine. But from that error it seems that my php file can't be fetched, which is weird because when I did it with an empty html file, it was in the same directory as the php file.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors. Also, the screenshot misses most of the error

Comment: N.B. `if (isset($_POST))` doesn't make a lot of sense. It'll always be there, even if there isn't actually any data in $_POST (which since you're sending JSON from the client-side, there won't be)

Comment: Why is there a POST request to `home.html?...` directly after this ...? I am guessing that is not a request you intended to make - but your button _submits_ the form it is in. And that form submission, which will load a new page, then of course cancels any fetch requests you might have going on. Add `type="button"` to that button, to make it a "click button" instead of a submit button.

Answer (score -3):

I recently had this problem, for me the reason was that the button submit the form, which terminates the ajax request.
I solved the problem by replacing the button with span which I styled as a button.

Comment: You know you can just put `type="button"` into the button to stop it submitting the form? You don't need to replace it completely.

Comment: In my case it worked in chrome but in firefox it kept submit the form.

Comment: I think you must be mistaken. Try it: https://jsfiddle.net/83san12v/ ...run that in Firefox and press the button. It won't submit the form.

Comment: Great thank you for the helpful comment, my code in production now works great and I don't intend to deal with it again if I don't have to.